# Background image sizes in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to find out exact resolutions for different mobiles. For launcher icons there are some standard resolutions like `36px 72 px 96px` for `xhdpi`. Please anyone can tell me what sizes should i use for `background images` so that they won't feel like stretched , blurred etc.

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)

Comment: Anyway I saw this question as first link at google and find useful link below, so I don't think this question deserves downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen ["Supporting Multiple Screens"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

It should answer all your questions about this. Also, I'm more or less quoting myself now. This question is [not original](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=different%20screen%20sizes%20%5Bandroid%5D) (link to SO search).