# Android Exception loading 9-patch image

Tags: android, cordova, nine-patch

I'm trying to implement a 9-patch splash screen for PhoneGap Android and I keep getting compiler exceptions.

I have a res/drawables/splash.xml containing:

```
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/splashimg" 
android:dither="false"/>
```

I have splashimg.9.png saved to res/drawable.  (Using [a test 9-patch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZv2V.png) as taken from [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices))

And I have the following in my DroidGap file:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

When I try to build, however, I get:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image
```

Any ideas?  I can get a normal splash screen working, just not a 9-patch...

Comment: check your 9 patch is in drawable folder and can you post it

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan I downloaded the sample image from http://i.stack.imgur.com/AZv2V.png and saved it to the drawable folder as splashimg.9.png.

Comment: this is not a valid 9 patch image

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan Do you know why?  I borrowed it from a tutorial at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices.  I thought it would be valid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I only had the XML and 9.png file in the res/drawable directory. As soon as I placed them into the other four directories, everything started working fine.