# Android background image size for XXHDPI

Tags: android, background, png, drawable

I need to set the background picture for my app, the only problem is that i dont know what size the image has to be for XXHDPI devices.

I read here for MDPI, HDPI and XHDPI devices, but nothing for XXHDPI:
[Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices/15744389#15744389)

So, what size does the background has to be for drawable-xxhdpi folder?

Answer (score 34):

MDPI is your baseline. Means the base size, which is ~160dpi. Every other density qualifier is calculated based on the baseline

HDPI is 1.5*MDPI

XHDPI is 2*MPDI

XXHDPI is 3*MDPI

XXXHDPI is 4*MDPI

Or, see this table for a better description

```
| Density Qualifier | Factor                 | DPI  | Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|-------------------|------------------------|------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ldpi              | MDPI / 1.33            | ~120 | Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| mdpi              | MDPI * 1               | ~160 | Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| hdpi              | MDPI * 1.5             | ~240 | Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| xhdpi             | MDPI * 2               | ~320 | Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| xxhdpi            | MDPI * 3               | ~480 | Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| xxxhdpi           | MDPI * 4               | ~640 | Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| nodpi             | See description        | n/a  | Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| tvdpi             | Recommended: MDPI*1.33 | ~213 | Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi. |
```

See this image for more information

[image]

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: i know that this works for icons, but does it apply for background also?

Comment: I'm so sorry. Didn't even see you replied to me... 

It depends on a lot of different things. But for smaller apps I would just skip hdpi, mdpi & ldpi and put all of it in /drawable Put high res images there and phones with lower density will scale them down.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html at this date still doesn't talk about xxhdpi ... I don't know how you came about that 3*mdpi but thx!

Comment: I don't know if it didn't say it when you posted the link, but now it says the following

`mdpi (medium) ~160dpi` and `xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi`. That's where I got MDPI * 3 from

Answer (score 2):

You need [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

and this:
MDPI: x1,
HDPI: x1.5,
XHDPI: x2,
XXHDPI: x3