# Image sizes for multiple android screens

Tags: java, android, xml

This has to be one of the most over asked questions on here which is often just directed to the android developer site. After reading the documentation, I just wanted to come here and clarify.

I understand the there must be different drawables for each screen size and density to create an optimized user experience. I want just a simple background image. Therefore I need to create a background image for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. After researching I found the following sizes for these size folders:

xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960
large (hdpi): 480x800
medium (mdpi): 320x480
small (ldpi): 240x320

resource answer: [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices/15744389#15744389)

But question, I didnt think ldpi was used or required anymore and where is xxhdpi?

After I have my image sizes I can center it and be good :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To create an image for different densities, you should follow the **2:3:4:6:8** scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively).

[image]

The sizes you provided already dont follow this pattern, so they are either wrong or outdated.

However, following your xhdpi value, we can get xxhdpi:

**xxlarge (xxhdpi): 960:1440**  xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960 large (hdpi): 480x800 medium (mdpi): 320x480 small (ldpi): 240x320.

(recomended to always round up to set of ten)

But as you can see it is not consistent with the other values, because they use a different ratio. So you will have to re-work your resources size to adapt them to the standard.

Ldpi is just not supported anymore by android iconography. Also discouraged.

Link with official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html).