# Android mocup design and splashes size

Tags: android, graphics

I want to start designing an app, and I have two questions:

1. What are the best screen sizes in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi which match all other devices  so I can design in that size?
2. What are exact sizes in pixels for splash screens?

Please don't just share a link , I read all articles on this site, but I could not find my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically creating splash screens for Android applications is a very bad practise unless it's a game.

Your questions sound a bit unclear, maybe you could be more specific. However, I will try to help you.

First of all you should get familiar with this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It's not a link to SO site.

On that web page you will find the following picture.

[image]

When you design for Android think about sizes in DPI. Your reference size bucket would be MDPI. If you create a bitmap 100x100px then you have to create separate bitmaps for other densities using factors: HDPI 1.5 (150x150px), XHDPI 2.0 (200x200px) and so on.

Splash screen is something that usually covers full screen but it can be created from parts. For example create NinePatch bitmap that is automatically scaled for any screen size, usually buttons use NinePatch for backgrounds. Next create separate bitmap with a logo or any other graphic that you wish to present. Avoid whitespaces in your bitmaps.
Parts of the splash screen would be joined and displayed by developer so you should not care about merging them anyhow.

I don't know if that's what you expected. I will try to update my answer if you provide more input.

Comment: This is likely the best possible answer to give. It's pretty unreasonable to give an *exact* pixel size because on Android, the screen sizes can vary so much, but with 9patch, you can make a splash be centered and expand outward.  As a good add-on, [this site](http://draw9patch.com) gives an interactive means of making 9patch images.

Comment: Can i design ui (mockup) in following sizes?
please see url - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices#answer-15744389

Comment: No one can answer that. It depends on the application and the number of different layouts. However, in most cases it's enough to cover devices, 7" tablets and 10" tablets. In portrait and landscape modes. So it gives you approximately 6 different mocks. At that stage you are not creating final bitmap so there is no need to worry about all kind of devices. By the way, have a look at lesson 5 of this course https://www.udacity.com/course/progress#!/c-ud853 and you can watch this course too https://www.udacity.com/course/ud849