# Android Application not Picking the proper size Icon or Image depending upon Device Size

Tags: android, app-store

I am developing one android application which may be run on mobile, tablet, or TV.

So I have crated separate size icons and images for each devices, and the icons and images are stored in  hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi folders.

When I install the application on mobile it picks the icon form mdpi folder.

When I install in tablet then also it pick the icon from mdpi folder, instead of xhdpi.

Same problem for images also.

Comment: What are the exact names of the folders you are using? Which devices are you testing on? How do you know it is choosing the "wrong" icon?

Comment: I have the same issue , May your image size not correct for e.g in your mdpi folder your image size is 100px in your hdpi should be 200px

Comment: I am using MOTO G(mobile), samsung Tab2, as the size of the icons are same (same small in Tab and Mobile) i can understand it picks the icon form same folder.

Comment: Icon Size - MDPI - 160 dpi, HDPI - 240 dpi, XHDPI - 320 dpi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)

Comment: I have created the icons from http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html. to avoid the mistake , but not working as expected