# Android splash screen dimensions

Tags: android, size, screen, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a splash screen on photoshop that will support every single device that runs Android. I've been reading around blogs and the android website and I see that you need to design your assets in dp, but I don't understand what that means. I understand the concept of dp, but I don't understand how to apply that on photoshop. I know the equivalent of a dp is pixels/(dpi/160), but I'm not sure what size (pixels) I should be using for each one of the different sizes (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi...). So if someone can let me know what the dimensions of my splash screens needs to be, as well as the resolution, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)

Comment: If you can use vector graphics like SVGs, you can save yourself a lot of headache of having to make multiple versions of assets at different resolutions for different devices. In such a scenario, you'd want to use something like Illustrator instead of Photoshop to create your splash screen graphics.

Answer (score 0):

```
ldpi = 320 x 426
mdpi = 320 X 470
hdpi = 480 x 640
xhdpi = 720 x 960
xxhdpi = 1080 X 1440
```

Answer (score 0):

strongly recommend that images are no larger than 2,000 pixels wide with no more than 72 dots per inch (dpi). This keeps your Splash page loading quickly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).