# What is the best bitmap size to insert into android studo?

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, heap-memory

I have a couple images that I am adding to android studio, however, I will the error that, the bitmap is to large. Additionally, larger bitmaps will increase my heap amount and create my app to run slower, therefore, I am asking what the ideal image size to upload is for a reasonable sized bitmap?

Comment: android studio or android sqlite ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with bitmaps? And when you write "Android Studio", do you actually mean Android Studio or are you trying to load pictures into `Bitmap`s in an Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like 'ideal size', read about [Android screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Every group of screen have a different size, so you should place as many images as screen group. You can read more in other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices).

If you want to make image smaller, you can use [Kraken](https://kraken.io/) for PNG images, or you can also convert them to the [WEBP format](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-webp).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need

Comment: @eli Mark my answer as a solution, you can also vote on it :)