# Image resolution for activity background

Tags: android, drawable

I'm working on an Android app that should be compatible with most recent devices, Nexus and Samsung for example.

I would like to have a background image for the first activity, but I don't know what is the resolution for this image, as in Nexus there is a software navigation bar, but in Samsung mobiles there is a hardware navigation bar that is not taken into consideration.

What are the resolutions of the image that I should ask to the graphic designer if I want to put the image as an activity background ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to be compatible on most of all devices, you will need to have **different resolutions**. For a background image, the dimensions can vary for devices, that is why Android Studio has the capability to have mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi. Each of these fit different devices to support all devices.

Here is a breakdown of what each of these dpi ratings are:

- **ldpi** (low) ~**120dpi**
- **mdpi** (medium) ~**160dpi**
- **hdpi** (high) ~**240dpi**
- **xhdpi** (extra-high) ~**320dpi**
- **xxhdpi** (extra-extra-high) ~**480dpi**
- **xxxhdpi** (extra-extra-extra-high) ~**640dpi** | **Launcher icon only!**

And, here is a breakdown of the resolutions for the dpi's:

- **320dp**: Normal phone screen: **240x320 ldpi**, **320x480 mdpi**, **480x800 hdpi**, etc.
- **480dp**: Tweener tablet like the Streak: **480x800 mdpi**
- **600dp**: a 7" tablet: **600x1024 mdpi**
- **720dp**: a 10" tablet: **720x1280 mdpi**, **800x1280 mdpi**, etc.

My suggestion would be to make the best quality image, then use the tool below:

- For the binaries for the tool, click [here](https://github.com/leocadiotine/fred).
- For the download, click [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5135185/blog/fred-1.0.jar). (Download in .jar format)

For more information, click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). If this post has helped, please mark it as correct for future readers.