# Pixel dimensions for different DPIs for a full screen image?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an activity with an image that is the same height as the screen. I tried going to easy route, and just using a really big image and then scaling it down within the app, but when I run it on a device with a smaller screen, I get an error saying the device ran out of memory. I was hoping to make several drawable folders for each dpi (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc.). I looked up the pixel dimensions for splash screens, but when I resize my image to fit those dimensions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744389/5909429), the image only fills about half the screen on my smaller device.

What dimensions should I actually use, or am I using the drawable folders wrong?

Comment: first of all use image view and set its scale type to fitxy and put your image i only drawable-xxxhdpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...]or am I using the drawable folders wrong?

Yes and no. I don't know about any "perfect" values for your picture dimensions, and I doubt that there are any, due to the fact that there are too many different phones to support.

The usage of dpi ensures that everything has the same *size*. If you were to put a ruler on your screens on a xxxhdpi and a ldpi device, both pictures would be the same size. This is dpi.

What you are trying to do is filling a phone screen. This has not much to do with dpi, but is about the actual pixel size of the screen. If you have a 1920x1080 phone display, you want an image with the same resolution. This does *not* say anything about dpi or screen density, and it has frankly nothing to do with it.

To properly scale down your image—and not running into OOM—you can either use a designated image loading library, like Glide, or Picasso, or you can take a look at `BitmapFactory` which lets you supply a `inSampleSize` to load the image in the size needed yourself. The official documentation can be found here at [Loading large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).