# Creating white splash screen with logo in the center

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a white splash screen with logo in the center. What is the best practice or the specifications of deliverable files I should provide to the Android developer. What are the sizes of logo image (px), resolution of images (dpi)? Is it applicable to give one large size and the developer resizes the logo image proportionally in the code per each screen resolution?

Comment: please prefer this so Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

with `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

For more info, follow Android reference : [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)