# android: image in different devices

Tags: android, android-image, pixel, hdpi, mdpi

I want to insert images in my android application, first I will be create the images with photoshop then insert it in the projetct.
I have a problem in the size of the images:
how convert dpi to width and height in pixels
LDPI,MDPI,HDPI,XHDPI,XXHDPI= width px * height px
I want to know the range of values that can the variables width and height.
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)

Answer (score 0):

LDPI = 120 pixels/inch

MDPI = 160 pixels/inch

HDPI = 240 pixels/inch

XHDPI = 320 pixels/inch

XXHDPI = 480 pixels/inch

XXXHDPI = 640 pixels/inch

These are approximations, actual device display resolutions vary somewhat

See this: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html