# Ideal splash screen image sizes (Android)

Tags: android

I know that this question has already been asked and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices), but time has passed and we have new devices with "crazy" resolutions and aspect ratios...

Based on that question, image sizes should be:

**PORTRAIT MODE**

MDPI is 320x480 dp = 320x480px (1x)

LDPI is 0.75 x MDPI = 240x360px

HDPI is 1.5 x MDPI = 480x720px

XHDPI is 2 x MDPI = 640x960px

XXHDPI is 3 x MDPI = 960x1440px

XXXHDPI is 4 x MDPI = 1280x1920px

**LANDSCAPE MODE**

MDPI is 480x320 dp = 480x320px (1x)

LDPI is 0.75 x MDPI = 360x240px

HDPI is 1.5 x MDPI = 720x480px

XHDPI is 2 x MDPI = 960x640px

XXHDPI is 3 x MDPI = 1440x960px

XXXHDPI is 4 x MDPI = 1920x1280px

1) Now that we have devices like Galaxy S7, Pixel XL (1440x2650) or Galaxy S8 (1440x2960) what should be ideal splash image sizes?

2) How should I include these resource for above mentioned devices? I need to maintain app which supports devices back to api 15...

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I received no answer from community I did it this way:

1) I included resources as:

S7 - "drawable-h640dp-xxxhdpi"

S8 - "drawable-h740dp-xxxhdpi"

2) It is compatible with older devices out of the box but it increases size of apk a lot which can be problem on old devices. Therefore; a a good solution is to use multiple apk for screen sizes / densities.

I hope it will help someone