# Splash Screen Image not showing on full screen using core SplashScreen library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-splashscreen

implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
I am using this library to show a splash screen and this shows my splash screen image in only a part of the screen I want the image to fill the full screen.
Here's my themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.News" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#EF9A9A</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name = "android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.News</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Here's my Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Splash"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my MainActivity

```
package com.example.news

import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
    private val tabList = listOf("Top", "Politics", "Technology")

    private val topNewsFragment = NewsFragment.newInstance("top")
    private val politicsNewsFragment = NewsFragment.newInstance("politics")
    private val technologyNewsFragment = NewsFragment.newInstance("technology")
    private val fragmentList = listOf(topNewsFragment,politicsNewsFragment,technologyNewsFragment)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        installSplashScreen()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,R.color.red))
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

        viewPager.adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager,lifecycle,fragmentList)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabList[position]

        }.attach()

    }
}
```

Also how can we increase the time for which splash screen is shown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)

Comment: @mujammil No, It doesn't