# AVD settings for extra large screen resolution

Tags: android

Can anybody please tell what are the correct settings for emulating extra large resolution devices in Android? I want to create this AVD for 720 x 960 resolution. What other settings like abstract lcd density and other such settings needs to be applied?

Comment: for which device you want to create avd

Comment: I need general settings. I am developing an app to support extra large resolution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6166685/1434631

Comment: @Nunu I need settings for xhdpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AVD` Manager, you can create XLarge Screens like `SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab` and many devices listed if u have downloaded them through `SDK Manager` of `Android`. If the devices are not listed while creating `AVD`, try to update run `SDK Manager` once and install them.

Comment: actually i want to test my app on extra large resolution but not on Tab. So, i need to create an AVD with custom settings. I am searching for those settings.

Comment: Do u find an option "Resolution" below "Built in" while creating AVD? Give the resolution u want to create... Note that the resolution u r giving is in pixels

Comment: I dnt know what hardware settings needs to be applied.

Comment: No need of Hardware setting to be modified. The emulator will be installed with default Hardware settings...

Comment: I have already tried that. Its not using the images stored in xhdpi drawable folder.

Comment: Obviously it doesnt take if u changes the resolution because "Built in" only takes the xhdpi images. I dont know y u r not intrested to use Galaxy tab AVD? if u use that it will take the images from the desired folder....

Comment: sorry if I am not clear about my question. I know the resolution i.e. 720 x 960 but i dont know the other settings needs to be applied. Besides i want to test my app on phones like Motorola Razr so i can't use Tab avd

Answer (score 1):

You should understand about dp in android to set abstract screen density. You can read here for more http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html