# how to define XML for multiple resolutions on android?

Tags: resolution

i  give you simple example. I have liner layout and simple 3 buttons. For fill linearlayout by 3 buttons I use weight (1,1,1,). Butonts resizes. Its OK.
But when I have buttons which consist from 3 shape (rectangle, rectangle, oval).

On tablet: Oval is resized to elipse 
on mini smart phone Oval is missing.

I know Shape is defined by dip, but i dont know how make Gui for more resolution.

3 xml to each resolution???

Comment: Can you give more details? Like frameworks, systems, languages used?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the answer to this StackOverflow question.

[StackOverflow - Android screen size HDPI, LDPI, MDPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166685/2830740)

It links to the Android developer guide relating to screen sizes.