# Convert px to dp and sp in /values/dimen.xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-screen-support

I know we should use dp/sp instead of px in UI design, but the UI designer I work with just gives me his design in pixels in 1280x720. 
How should I convert the pixels in 1280x720 to dp/sp, and support multiple screens?

I checked the doc, 30px in 1280x720 = 15dp in xhdpi. Should I make a `/values-xhdpi/dimen.xml` file in my project? And what about other resolutions? How should I deal with `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi`?

Also, I got the text sizes in pixels too. Do I need to do the same thing as I did with dp?

Comment: no need to make different values folder

Comment: go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this -

1) [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

2) [Android screen size HDPI, LDPI, MDPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166677/android-screen-size-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi)

Hope it will help :)