# What are the mandatory screen size need to be used like xhdpi,xxhdpi?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have few doubts.I am developing the project from the scratch.Whether I need to maintain all the drawable folders like

```
-drawable-ldpi
-drawable-mdpi 
-drawable-hdpi
-drawable-xhdpi
-drawable-xxhdpi
-drawable-xxxhdpi
```

or I can use these folders

```
-drawable-xhdpi
-drawable-xxhdpi
-drawable-xxxhdpi.
```

Because If I use all the drawable screen size my apk size is increasing.I think currently ldpi,mdpi and hdpi screen size is not in market.So I am planning to omit ldpi,mdpi and hdpi. Please share me your suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166677/android-screen-size-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi

Comment: I am planning to go with xhdpi,xxhdpi and xxxhdpi or its a mandatory to use all screen sizes.

Comment: actually its depends on you. If you are targeting small screen size than it is required otherwise no requirement. Test your app with different screen size phones. Basically hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi are enough and for more info try this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: okay thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer to this [DOCUMENTATION](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-image-scaling) and also this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)**

```
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| Density Bucket | Screen Density | Physical Size | Pixel Size                    | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| ldpi           | 120 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 120 dpi = 60x60 px   | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| mdpi           | 160 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 160 dpi = 80x80 px   | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| hdpi           | 240 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 240 dpi = 120x120 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| xhdpi          | 320 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 320 dpi = 160x160 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| xxhdpi         | 480 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 480 dpi = 240x240 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| xxxhdpi        | 640 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 640 dpi = 320x320 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

> **Also if you are worried about increased APK size due to this, you can use vector drawables.**

**Please refer this Link for [understanding vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)**

Comment: Reason for DownVote?

Comment: Whether I need to put vector drawable in all screen sizes or I can maintain just a single folder drawable.

Comment: Yes, vector drawables are added in only one folder "drawable" only.

Comment: That's why I suggested you for the same. It will remove extra efforts and provide good quality in lesser size

Answer (score -1):

***Screen sizes for android::***

**Dimensions:-**

**LDPI**:
Portrait: 200x320px
Landscape: 320x200px

**MDPI**:
Portrait: 320x480px
Landscape: 480x320px

**HDPI**:
Portrait: 480x800px
Landscape: 800x480px

**XHDPI**:
Portrait: 720px1280px
Landscape: 1280x720px

**XXHDPI**:
Portrait: 960px1600px
Landscape: 1600x960px

**XXXHDPI**:
Portrait: 1280px1920px
Landscape: 1920x1280px

Comment: The density is independent of screen size. Dpi is the amount of pixels per inch, meaning 1080x1920 can be XXXHDPI on a small device, but XHDPI on a bigger device (bigger = bigger physical screen)

Comment: There is nothing mention in question about desnsity. That's why Answer contains information about SCREEN SIZE for devices of all different sizes ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi & xxxhdpi either in portrait or landscape.

Comment: The screen size buckets are defined through the density of the screen, not the actual screen size

Comment: That's why I added in px when you missed it.

Comment: And also drawables are made in px.

Comment: ***The screen size classes are independent of pixels***. Of course drawables are made in pixels because dp is an Android-specific unit that converts to pixels based on the density of the device. The screen sizes (MDPI, HDPI, etc) are defined by the density. XXXHDPI has a very high pixel density, where as LDPI has a very low pixel density. The actual amount of pixels the device has doesn't define the classes; it's the pixel density that matters here